# extract NP-VP-NP from Stanford dependency parse tree

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, opennlp

I need to extract triplets of the form `NP-VP-NP` from the dependency parse tree produced as the output of lexalized parsing in Stanford Parser.

Whats the best way to do this.
e.g. If the parse tree is as follows:

```
(ROOT
  (S
    (S
      (NP (NNP Exercise))
      (VP (VBZ reduces)
        (NP (NN stress)))
      (. .))
    (NP (JJ Regular) (NN exercise))
    (VP (VBZ maintains)
      (NP (JJ mental) (NN fitness)))
    (. .)))
```

I need to extract 2 triplets:

1. Exercise-reduces-stress and
2. Regular Exercise-maintains-mental fitness

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two natural options here. One is to run [Semgrex](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/semgraph/semgrex/SemgrexPattern.html) over the dependency tree (side note: what you have in the question is a constituency tree), with a pattern like:

`{pos:/V.*/}=verb >/.subj.*/ {}=subject >/.obj/ {}=object`

Another option is to use the [Stanford Open IE](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/openie.shtml) system. This will give you a more broad semantics of '(subject; relation; object)' triples, where the relation does not have to be a verb.

Comment: Please provide any link with relevant example code. I badly need one.